# STL list function that deletes N'th element from list and replaces it with M'th element from the same list C++. Must use re-linking

Tags: c++, function, linked-list, stl

so I've come across a problem, i am able to delete the N'th element using the code below, but i have completely no idea how to re-link *links* in order to get my desired result.

An example with the result needed. So the list is {1,3,5,4} i need to be able to pass 2 parameters to function N and M. For example N is 2 which in this case is 3, taken consecutively, M is 4, which is also taken consecutively and in this case is 4. And the result i'm hoping for is {1,4,5} or at least {1,4,5,4} (tough i'm not sure if extra steps are needed for the second result).I attached my code below and the function i was working on is the deleteNode, i would be really grateful if someone could help me out.

```
using namespace std;

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data  = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}

void deleteNode(struct Node **head_ref, int N)
{
    // Store head node
    struct Node* temp = *head_ref, *prev;


    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == N)
    {
        *head_ref = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }


    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != N)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }


    if (temp == NULL) return;

    prev->next = temp->next;

    free(temp);
}


void printList(struct Node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Node* sar = NULL;

    push(&sar,4);
    push(&sar, 5);
    push(&sar, 3);
    push(&sar, 1);

    puts("Linked lists: ");
    printList(sar);
    deleteNode(&sar, 3);
    puts("\nList after deletion: ");
    printList(sar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you remove `using namespace std;` (which is useless in your code anyway), you have C, not C++. You don't `struct Node* new_node` in C++. You can drop the leading `struct`. You also should use `new`, rather than `malloc`. You have underfined behaviour in your code, because you treat raw memory like it was `Node`. It's not. It's C++, not C, again.

Comment: The title of your question starts with *STL List function* -- Where is the STL in any of this code?  In C++, STL has `std::list`.

Comment: Copy M's value to N, then delete M.

Comment: Still the best way to solve pointer-related problems: take out some paper and a pen. Work it out by drawing boxes and arrows.

Comment: What does "STL list function" mean in this context?

Comment: @Slava Just a regular function, that has 3 parameters if i'm not mistaken the list itself (i'm not sure if necessary tho),  N and M.

Comment: So STL stands for "just a regular function"?

Comment: @Slava I'm not sure what exactly ur trying to accomplish here, but i'm looking for some help for function that helps me in the problem described above, i'm not looking for clarification what are other things such as struct, definitions of STL function or whatever, as long as it helps me and is considered a function i'm extremely grateful.

Comment: I am trying to understand what STL means in this context, because it does not make any sense to me and I cannot answer a question that I do not understand.

Comment: @Slava As in this whole program should be done using STL:list container, i guess i just need a regular, sorry if i explained something incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you work a tad you'd be much better of with the solution that rcgldr offered.

That being said, if you're keen on using your homemade list and not using C++ much at all really, you can try something along these lines:

Caution, this solution is way less elegant than something using std::list (again, see rcgldr's answer) and I have not unit tested it properly, you know the drill, don't use this as is :)

```cpp
int replaceNode(int indexToReplace, int indexToReplaceWith, Node **head_ref) {
  assert(head_ref != nullptr && "don't pass nulls for head_ref");

  auto freeNode = [](Node **node) {
    assert(node != nullptr && "don't pass nulls for node");
    delete *node;
    *node = nullptr;
  };

  Node *toReplace = nullptr, *toReplaceWith = nullptr,
       *previousFromToReplaceWith = nullptr;

  int index = 1; // 1 based or so it seems

  for (Node *cursor = *head_ref, *previous = nullptr; cursor != nullptr;) {
    // search for both nodes in one go
    if (index == indexToReplace) {
      toReplace = cursor;
    }
    if (index == indexToReplaceWith) {
      toReplaceWith = cursor;
      // for the one we delete, we also keep its previous
      previousFromToReplaceWith = previous;
    }

    // you can and should break early in here, by checking agains null
    if (toReplaceWith != nullptr && toReplace != nullptr) {
      break;
    }
    ++index;

    previous = cursor;
    cursor = cursor->next;
  }

  if (toReplaceWith == nullptr || toReplace == nullptr) {
    // set errors, maybe even set a string error, or god forbid, throw :p
    return -1;
  }

  // if it's not the first item, skip it
  if (previousFromToReplaceWith) {
    previousFromToReplaceWith->next = toReplaceWith->next;
  }
  // you only want the value, right? 
  // won't work that well for other types where you'd just switch 
  // the nodes by doing iterator things, i.e. using some 'std::list<T>::splice' 
  // but works for your 'int' case
  toReplace->data = toReplaceWith->data;
  freeNode(&toReplaceWith);
  return 0;
}
```

You can probably factor our some of the things I've put and combine them with your delete node.

Also it requires C++11 but I believe that's not asking much in 2020, still, compile with your fav compiler adding your specific standard flag.

Answer (score 1):

If this is STL std::list, then an iterator should be used. Use std::next() to advance an iterator from std::list::begin() to the desired node. Use std::list::erase() to delete a node. Use two iterators with std::list::splice() to move a node.